# What does it mean : Le capitalisme, c'est l'exploitation de l'homme par l'homme ; et le marxisme, C'est le contraire.

Tags: expressions

Le capitalisme, c'est l'exploitation de l'homme par l'homme ; et le marxisme, C'est le contraire. (attributed to Jeanson but probably not invented by him)

What does it mean? To be particular, what does it mean by the last part “C'est le contraire”? Does it mean as literally that there’s no exploitation? Or is it a irony satire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is mere sarcasm: "c'est le contraire" should be understood as "it is the other way round".

A more common usage would be for instance:

> En France, les voitures ont le volant à gauche, et on roule à droite. En Angleterre, c'est le contraire: les voitures ont le volant à droite, et on roule à gauche.

So in Jeanson's quote, it means that in capitalism, men exploit men, whereas in communism, it is the other way round, and men exploit men... which means that even though they are in theory total opposites, actually, communism and capitalism end up in the same inegalitarian mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Man A exploits man B in Capitalism: The wealthy exploits the poor.
Man B exploits man A in a Marxist society. The poor takes everything from the wealthy.

Comment: That understanding can't but catch one's attention, but on second thought it's not flawless. In the so called class struggle the wealthy is considered to be exploiting the poor over historic periods of time but when it comes to the poor taking from the wealthy it's always  a question of a one time happening, after which Marxism does go on (without the wealthy); isn't that aspect your idea implies invalidating whatever justification of it that could be made?

Comment: That understanding can't but catch one's attention, but on second thought it's not flawless. In the so called class struggle the wealthy is considered to be exploiting the poor over historic periods of time but when it comes to the poor taking from the wealthy it's always a question of a one time happening, after which Marxism does go on (without the wealthy); I'm afraid this aspect of the matter, which your idea cannot encompass, makes of this very idea a dead end.

Answer (score 2):

Comme vous le décelez, il peut être question d'un contraire sur un premier plan ou sur un second.

Selon le premier schéma, où « le contraire » signifie une interversion du sujet et du complément d'agent (homme, homme) ce que ce très ingénieux trait d'esprit permet de nous dire en peu de mots, c'est que le capitalisme et le marxisme c'est blanc bonnet et bonnet blanc; que l'on partage cette position, évidemment, est une toute autre question. Cependant si l'on considère que Jeanson ait été un homme de gauche, il n'y a pas d'autre choix que de se restreindre à la seconde possibilité, c'est à dire une opposition (ou contraire) sur le plan de la signification du mot « exploitation »; le contraire ou opposé serait par exemple « enrichissement » et cela fait de l'énonciation un tout aussi ingénieux trait d'esprit, duquel est cependant exclu l'élément de "gros rire" qui fait partie de la première interprétation et c'est alors  assez malheureux pour Jeanson que la première interprétation doive à jamais rester attachée à son idée.

Comment: Jeanson n'était pas un « homme de gauche ». Il abhorrais le communisme (le stalinisme) comme le capitalisme. C'était un anarchiste à la critique acerbe mais sans écarter le *gros rire*, tendance « Le canard enchaîné », voire « Charlie-Hebdo ».

Comment: @Eh bien, alors cela nous laisse la première possibilité comme celle à retenir. Merci de cet important renseignement; je n'ai pas été capable de définir son allégeance politique à partir de l'article le concernant dans Wikipédia.

Comment: Oui, **absence d'allégeance** décrirait même bien son cas.